# SecurityBits and Sequence in ListTemplate

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint ListTemplate.In elements.xml i have the following tag.What is SecurityBits and Sequence in the below tag?

```
   <ListTemplate
    Name="doclib"
    Type="1116"
    BaseType="1"
    OnQuickLaunch="FALSE"
    SecurityBits="11"
    Sequence="110"
    DisplayName="Sample"
    Description="Library to store data."
    Image="/_layouts/images/itdl.png"
    NewPage= "SL/Pages/XSLnew.aspx"
    Category="Libraries"
    DocumentTemplate="101"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SecurityBits="11"` means **`Users can read and edit all items.`**

`Sequence="110"` means **`110 is the ordering priority to use for the list template on the Create page`**

Read [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462947.aspx) for more information

Comment: OK that's fine,Is there any other files other than elements.xml that we have to consider while creating a ListTemplate?

Comment: you better ask separate question for that